# Android Phonegap Black Screen appears while switching from one activity to another

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a Hybrid Phonegap/Native Android app. While transitioning from ActivityA  to ActivityB a **black screen** appears. I would like to prevent the flicker before showing ActivityB.

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class ActivityA extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}

public class ActivityB extends DroidGap 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();       
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/view.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you add some code what you have tried??

Comment: Add this css in css file: html, body { background:#ffffff ;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}

Comment: Yes i was able to solve the problem. By going to the res/xml/config.xml setting the background color as follows <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xffffffff"/>